# Is there an incoming any kind of mail log for Google Apps?

Tags: email, log-files, logging, g-suite, gmail

About 3 months ago we switched to Google Apps from a terrible webmail application provided by our web host. We have since been told by a customer that he sent a cancellation email that we never received. Is there any way to determine if the message was ever received by Google and was subsequently deleted or if it never arrived in the first place? There is a debate over whether this message was in fact sent due to other events that have taken place.

Comment: It isn't directly related, but see this question [about keeping a copy of Google mail](http://serverfault.com/questions/179312/google-apps-bcc-all-inbound-and-outbound-email).  Basically if you pay for the Message Discovery or Postini services you would be able to answer this type of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best answer to this question is No. Typically you'll only be able to get a mail server admin to trace a message if you can provide message headers. Without an email, you can't provide those, so he would pretty much have to sift through endless logs and spend in inordinate amount of time that he would consider a waste. Even with the headers, it can be a lot of work. So really, no, you're not likely going to be able to do that.
Did you check the spam/junk mail folder?

Comment: +1 There are things you can setup in advanced with Google, but there is almost no way you are going to anything after the fact.